# Verb tense in relative clauses ("Will the last to leave turn off the lights")

Tags: infinitives, relative-clauses, present-tense

> Will the person who is last to leave please turn off the lights?

I don't get why we use "leave" here. According to my guide book, it is in the present tense in relative clauses.

Comment: Verbs of any tense or aspect can appear in a relative clause; are you sure the guide book is saying what you think it is saying? Here *to leave* is a [to-infinitive](http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-infinitive) modifying *last*. The example sentence as written is fine, though I, and probably most Americans at least, would more likely formulate it as *Would the last person to leave*

Comment: According to your guide book, *what* is in the present tense here? If you mean "leave," it is the infinitive *to leave*. It used like "Are you the last one to leave?" Although infinitives don't really have tenses, they can show aspect *to have left.*

Answer (score 1):

> Will the person who is last to leave please turn off the lights?

This could also be stated as

> Will the person who is the last one to leave please turn off the lights?

without the relative clause, the sentence is:

> Will the person please turn off the lights?

So the relative clause is:

*who is the last (one) to leave*

As you can see, the relative clause really changes the sentence. Without it, we really do not know who "the person" is. The relative clause is unrestricted, because it provides information vital to the sentence. The relative clause tells us *who* is.

*To leave* is just an infinitive that is the object of the *the last one*.

You can have the question:

> "Who" is the last (one) to leave?

In your sentence, that question is used as the relative clause, with the unknown *who* modifying *person*.

> Will the person who is the last one to leave please turn off the lights?

You can also state this sentence as

> Will the last person to leave please turn off the lights?

There is no relative clause in this sentence. So it is simpler and maybe more common.

Answer (score 0):

Will the person who is last to leave please turn off the lights?

> Will the person

which person?

> who is last to leave

the person who exits the room last

what should that person do?

> turn off the lights

It's perfectly fine English. I remember teachers always saying things like this to students when leaving the classroom to go to recess.

It's not known who the person will be that leaves the room last as of yet. But whomever that person ends up being, the teacher gave them the responsibility to shut the lights off ahead of time.

Instead of the teacher saying

> Whichever one of you students is last to leave this room, turn off the damn lights!

She/he just phrased it as a question to sound more polite.